# How to represent the z-axis of a coordinate frame B using spherical coordinates defined in another coordinate frame A

Tags: matrices, rotations, spherical-coordinates

I have two 3D rotation matrices, A and B. The columns of these rotation matrices can of course be interpreted as representing the x-, y- an z-bases of two new coordinate frames. What I want to know is, how can I define the z-basis of coordinate frame B in spherical coordinates defined in coordinate frame A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $R^P_Q$ denotes the rotation matrix whose columns represent the coordinate axes of the frame $Q$ expressed in the coordinate frame $P$. If I understand your statements correctly, you have $R^E_A$ and $R^E_B$, where $E$ is some reference coordinate frame, and you seek $R^A_B$. The z-axis of the frame $B$ expressed in frame $A$ is simply the third column of this matrix.
$$
R^A_B = R^A_E R^E_B = (R^E_A)^{-1}R^E_B
$$

Since you already have the right hand side of this equation, $R^A_B$ is readily obtained and you can extract its third column which I denote by $(x,y,z)$. Now, you can simply convert it into spherical coordinates using the relevant formulas for coordinate transformations.
See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Coordinate_system_conversions) for instance.